# Ruby mixins working with instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins, instance-variables

One of classes in an application is grown too much and I would like to group it's methods in some way.

One of ways could be to split Ruby class source into multiple files.

Ruby has a native mechanism to do this called mixins, but mixins are just isolated pieces of code which could be linked to any class. Therefore here is the question:

What is a drawback of working from mixins with instance-wide variables (for example `@socket` in my case)? Can mixins freely work with these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ruby's variables are not declared, but are implicit, and ruby as a whole is duck-typed, there is no problem for a class/module to *assume* that there is a variable names `@something`, and it will work correctly, as long as it is there.

So the answer to your question is - yes, mixins freely work with shared instance variables.